# Virtualbox hook into host machine

Tags: scripting, virtualbox, hook

I want to write a script that can add new hosts to /etc/hosts from within a virtual machine as I use VMs for web development and need to set up virtualhosts that are accessible from the host machine.

Obviously I can do this manually, but where's the fun in that?

I was wondering if there's a way to communicate with the host machine other than via the network - my guess is no but maybe there is something?

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot do this. You need a network connection to be able to talk to the virtual machine/host. You can make a script that populates your host machine hosts file with the VM's hostname though.

I have no idea why I added this as a comment oops.

Comment: Lol, me neither ;)